# How do I make my hamburger menu be converted into a horizontal one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm basically making a responsive web page on a mobile first design for my school assignment. I made my hamburger menu but I'm having trouble converting it to a normal horizontal menu. I have a media query at 1280px as well and not entirely sure what to put into my media query as I tried inline-block for the nav elements and it didn't work.

Here's my code:

```js
$(".cross").hide();
$(".navholding").hide();
$(".hamburger").click(function() {
  $(".navholding").slideToggle("slow", function() {
    $(".hamburger").hide();
    $(".cross").show();
  });
});

$(".cross").click(function() {
  $(".cross").hide();
  $(".navholding").slideToggle("slow", function() {
    $(".hamburger").show();
  });
});
```

```css
.hamburger {
  transform: translateY(-80px);
  height: 65px;
  width: 65px;
  background-color: #b56969;
  margin-left: 20px;
  background: url(images/Hamburger.png);
  background-size: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.cross {
  background: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0;
  padding: 7px 15px 0px 15px;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 3em;
  line-height: 65px;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  z-index: 101;
}

nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  text-align: left;
}

nav ul,
nav:active ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background: black;
  height: 100%;
  top: 65px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
}

nav li {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px 0;
  margin: 0;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: hidden;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: black;
  transform: translateY(-75px);
}

li a {
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 20pt;
  color: #b56969;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #333333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <div class="hamburger"></div>
  <div class="cross">&#10006;</div>
  <ul class="navholding">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"> About Me </a></li>
    <li><a href="#"> Services </a></li>
    <li><a href="#"> Hobbies </a></li>
    <li><a href="#"> Work </a></li>
    <li><a href="#"> Contact </a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Could you prepare a Fiddle replicating the issue so we can help you debug faster.

Comment: @SamApostel I agree that hamburger are a bit annoying. they are usually putted in the dead zone (where the thump can't reach without stretching)

Comment: @SamApostel Sorry abt that, I'm not too sure abt the question etiquette in here yet. I'll make sure I'll do one up, should I have another question and thanks for making the fiddle!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could give you current nav an id of mobile, then create a second nav with an id of desktop.

Make nav#desktop {display: none;}

Then use media queries to display: none; on nav#mobile, and display: inherit on nav#desktop.

I had to create my own hamburger here because yours was linked to an image, but the idea is there.

Resize the screen to see the change.

Best,
Levi

**UPDATE:** As Sam pointed out, this can be done with only CSS, which I believe he means it can be done without two navs.
Code is updated.

In the media query, display: none; on the hamburger.
display: block; on the ul.navholding.

Your css can be cleaned up quite a bit, I think that is where the issues are coming in.

```js
$('#nav-icon1').click(function() {
    $('#nav_list').toggleClass('active');
  });
```

```css
ul li {
    display: inline-block;
  }

  .navholding {
    display: none;
  }

  #nav_list.active {
    display: inherit;
  }

  /* Hamburgesa Icono de Navegación =========================================== */
  #nav-icon1 {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 10px 10px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
    transition: .5s ease-in-out;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 10000;
  }

  #nav-icon1 span {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    height: 3px;
    width: 25px;
    background: #282828;
    opacity: 1;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
    transition: .25s ease-in-out;
    z-index: 10000;
  }

  #nav-icon1 span:nth-child(1) {
    top: 15px;
    left: 7.5px;
  }

  #nav-icon1 span:nth-child(2) {
    top: 23px;
    left: 7.5px;
  }

  #nav-icon1.cross span {
    background: #8a1913;
  }

  #nav-icon1.cross span:nth-child(1) {
    top: 22px;
    left: 7.5px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(135deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(135deg);
    transform: rotate(135deg);
  }

  #nav-icon1.cross span:nth-child(2) {
    top: 22px;
    left: 7.5px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-135deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-135deg);
    transform: rotate(-135deg);
  }
  /* Final de la Hamburgesa Icono de Navegación =============================== */

  @media screen and (min-width: 1025px) {
    div#nav-icon1 {
      display: none;
    }

    .navholding {
      display: block;
    }
  }
```

```html
<nav>
          <div id="nav-icon1">
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
          </div>
          <ul id="nav_list" class="navholding">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> About Me </a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Services </a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Hobbies </a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Work </a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Contact </a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
        
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I don't think this is optimal since a css only solution is possible, but it works so yeah...

Comment: @SamApostel Thanks for the comment. I have updated the code to use only one nav. I believe that is what you meant.

Comment: Hey thanks for the solution, this worked aft some tweaking of my own and your explanation was easy to follow! @LeviStroop

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to post this here even if there's already an accepted answer because this is (in my opinion) the clean way of doing this.

If anybody needs any explanation on how or why something works, comment and I'll add to this post.

```js
function burgerSwitch(nav) {
    if (nav.className == "open") {
        nav.className = "close";
    } else {
        nav.className = "open";
    }
}
```

```css
   nav ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
nav ul li{
  float:left; /*instead of 'display:inline-block;' to make hamburger easier*/
  width: calc( (100vw - 40px ) / 6);/*6 = number of navitems you have*/
  list-style-type: none;
  
}
nav ul li a {
  background-color: #2fa35f;
  display:block;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid green;
  width:100%; //expand to entire li
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #3bcc77;
}

@media (max-width: 1000px) {
  
  burgerButton {
    display: block; 
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #d84b3e;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-bottom:5px;
  }
  burgerButton:hover{
    background-color:#b74137;
  }
  burgerButton:after{
    position: absolute;
    left: 20px;
    top: 3px;
    font-family: Arial Black;
    font-size: 40px;
  }
  nav.open burgerButton:after {
    content: '\00d7';
  }

  nav.close burgerButton:after {
    content: '\2261';
  }
  nav.close ul { 
    display: none; /*if nav has tag 'close', don't display list*/
  }
  nav ul li { 
    width: calc(100vw - 40px);
  }
}
```

```html
<nav class="close" id="nav">
    <burgerButton class="open" onclick="burgerSwitch(this.parentNode);">
    </burgerButton>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> About Me </a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> Services </a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> Hobbies </a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> work </a></li>
        <li><a href="#"> contact </a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```